# Check telnet connection with server IP and Port number in JScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tcp, websocket, telnet

I need to test telnet connection to the server in my local pc. My pc don't have any server side languages like PHP, NodeJS,.. I want to do this in basic JavaScript or chrome extension from latest chrome. I have checked with websocket HTML5. But, it was not working. Here's my code,

```
<script>
 var connection = new WebSocket('ws://10.0.30.1:80');

 connection.onopen = function () {
  connection.send('Ping'); // Send the message 'Ping' to the server
 };

</script>
```

Lets explain what's my mistake and give me a solution if any other possible.

Comment: You could use [chrome apps](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/telnet) to achieve that.

Comment: "My pc don't have any server side languages like PHP, NodeJS,."
Since @Haibara Ai already provided you an answer, I'll just answer this one.

Download Python and run this on your terminal:

python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000

Now you have a local server on port 8000.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Unless you set up a proxy server, a websocket can only communicate with a websocket server.

Comment: Is any other ways to test telnet connection to the server in my local pc?

Comment: what about a telnet client?